# Save telegram bot logs in a text file

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

A telegram bot I created in python uses pyTelegramBotAPI API.
To review logs, I was advised to use this line:

```
logger = telebot.logger
```

Now I can see my logs only in the terminal I'm running the bot with and when I close this terminal, the log data is lost.

How can I save this logs to a text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I read in documentation [here](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#logging), it should be possible to use Python's handler to logger.

Have you tried something like this

```
import logging
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.basicConfig(filename='filename.log', level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```